How to properly index a database table where is 20 columns which can be use for filtering data?
I have a database table with dozens of columns, out of which 20 are used to filter data in the database table. The table has 2 million rows. A simplified structure of the table looks like this:
cars:
- id
- name
- headline
- description
- color_id
- brand_id
- manucturer_id
- engine_id
- tires_id
- first_used
- price_start
- price_end
- fuel_type
- mileage
- registration
- power
- vehicle_type
- seats
- doors
- body
- sliding_doors
- ...

I have a big form on a page where users can enter the parameters of the car they're searching form and the Ruby on Rails backend with PostgreSQL database will provide the relevant selection of cars based on the entered parameters.
This solution worked when there was thousands or tens of thousands cars in the database. When growing it to hundreds thousands or millions of cars, the performance is bad and it takes over a minute to deliver the results.
I started adding indices on the columns that are in the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses, but this didn't help much. I was thinking about using compounded indices, but I don't know how to apply them (and even if it is a suitable approach here), because there can be an arbitrary mix of parameters - eg. doors+power, or registration+price_end+mileage+color_id+body and so on.
What is the best practice to enhance these cases? For these cases, how to structure the database? Is PostgreSQL suitable for this scenario, or are there better choices - such as MongoDB (I never worked with it on production)?

First, figure out why it is so slow to start with.  Is should not take 2 minutes to search 2 million rows, even if there is no usable index on the table at all.  EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)

filter can use from 1 to any amount of columns, so then

it's better to add index to high selective columns (columns with unique values, ids of relative table)

index for low selective columns like vehicle_type, fuel_type, seats doors are not required, database will use seq scan in any case for such columns and scan full table

no need in composite index - only index for each column separately

for text search use gin index (for description)

you can use partitioning for table and split it to smaller tables by some condition

use search engines like elasticsearch, search will be faster and will unload main database


